# Can I use .gitignore or .git/info/exclude to impede specific users from pulling/pushing files that are deemed "restricted" to them?

Tags: windows, git, gitignore, git-bash, openssh

I'm hosting a bare repository on Windows Server 2008 with Windows Git and OpenSSH. 
For legal reasons, I want some files to be inaccessible for a specific user but remain accessible to all other users. In other words, I want certain "restricted" files to be ignored (non-pullable) for a specific user.

Assume we have two users (Administrator and Guest) and a Git repository with 2 files : (a.txt and b.txt).

Assume "b.txt" is a restricted file that Guest should not have access to.

`git clone guest@ipaddress:C:/path/to/repository.git` or 
`git pull guest@ipaddress:C:/path/to/repository.git`

should clone or pull "a.txt"

`git clone administrator@ipaddress:C:/path/to/repository.git` or 
`git pull administrator@ipaddress:C:/path/to/repository.git`

should clone or pull both files.

Is there a way to achieve this result with .gitignore or .git/info/exclude?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve this result with .gitignore or .git/info/exclude?

No.

Git is all about *commits*, and pull (really, `git fetch`) and push operations transfer *commits*.  Commits *contain* files—a commit consists partly of data (a snapshot) and partly of metadata (information *about* the snapshot)—and you either have a commit, in which case you have *all* the files, or you don't have a commit, in which case you *don't* have all the files.

Files that need restrictions for whatever reasons—legal, corporate, or otherwise—must either not be in Git at all, or stored in some sort of pre-secured fashion (e.g., encrypted).  In general the "not in Git at all" approach tends to work best.  Consider storing, in Git, the URL of a restricted Web site that stores the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to restrict user access to only parts of a repository.  gitignore files are designed to prevent people from accidentally checking in code they didn't intend, not to restrict access to code already in the repository.

Even solutions that limit access to refs can be bypassed by a clever attacker in a way that lets them exfiltrate data from the repository.  You should assume anyone with read access to a repository can read all of the objects in that repository; if you need to restrict some users' access to certain data, it needs to either be encrypted or live in a different repository.